# Which special file holds Microphone input?

Tags: devices, microphone

There is a special file for everything: `/dev/tty` for the terminal, `/dev/sda` for a drive, and two random number generators: `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom`. Yet I can't find the special file(s) for raw microphone input. What is/are the name(s) of the file(s)?

If there isn't a special file, is there a program that will give such a stream via a pipe, or similar behaviour?

Comment: I'm also don't know it, but I guess it's probably gonna be something inside `/dev/snd/`.

Comment: @Rapti Hmm... I'll have a look.

Comment: No such luck. When I ran `sudo cat` on them, it either complained `file descriptor in bad state`, `no such device or address` or `invalid argument`. (`tac` said `invalid argument` too; it isn't just a bug with `cat`).

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I don't remember saying that :P

Answer (score 7):

that depends on the sound system running on your system. Search for alsa/pulse/jack/oss/whatever interface and you'll find plenty of information.

For example if you are using PulseAudio (which seams to be the standard today) you can use pacat/parec to get streams from your audio input. Just have a look at

```
man pacat
```

and you will find out that you can do

```
pacat -r | whatever
```

to redirect raw pcms to whatever you want.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This is very helpful. If you have any extra details (the format? 2 bytes? 1?) please add them to the answer.
I was looking for a special file which I could read bytes from; if this behaves in a similar way, could you add that to the answer as well?